# How to make an object constructor in JavaScript;

Tags: javascript, object-construction

Could you please explain me what's wrong in the following code?

```
function box (width, height, color) {
    this.width=width;
    this.height=height;
    this.color=color;
    this.style.width=width;
    this.style.height=height;
    this.style.backgroundColor=color;
}

var box1 = new box (100, 100, 'red');

document.body.appendChild(box1);
```

Comment: `box1` is a not a DOM element so you can't append it to another DOM element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `createElement` and pass it the parameters as follows:

```js
function box (width, height, color) {
  this.element = document.createElement('div');
  this.element.style.width=width+'px';
  this.element.style.height=height+'px';
  this.element.style.backgroundColor=color;
  return this.element;
}

var box1 = box (100, 100, 'red');

document.body.appendChild(box1);
```

Comment: There's no point to using `new` and adding a property to the object that `new box` creates if you return the DOM element out of `box`. Nothing will keep the object `new box` created...

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that `box` doesn't create a DOM element. You can't just append any object to the DOM, it has to be a DOM node of some kind (element, text node, etc.).

If you did have `box` create a DOM element, you wouldn't want to store `width`, `height`, and `color` on it directly, just in its `style` object.

Since the object created when you use `new` will get thrown away, I'd use `createBox` instead and not use `new` with it:

```js
function createBox(width, height, backgroundColor) {
    const element = document.createElement("div");
    element.style.width = width + "px";
    element.style.height = height + "px";
    element.style.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
    return element;
}

document.body.appendChild(
    createBox(100, 100, "red")
);
```

---

**If** you weren't wanting to create a DOM element, then the problem with `this.style.width=width` is that it's trying to assign to `undefined`, because `this` doesn't have a `style` property, so `this.style` is `undefined`. If you want to create an object from various properties, you can use an object literal:

```
function Box(width, height, color) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.color = color;
    this.style = {width, height, backgroundColor: color};
}
```

(Note that I changed `box` to `Box`. The overwhelming convention in JavaScript is that constructor functions (ones you call via `new` or similar) start with an uppercase character.)

But if you're creating a DOM element instead, it'll have a `style` object already.

I should note that I've used shorthand properties for `width` and `height` there, which were added in ES2015 and so nearly universally supported, but not by obsolete browsers like IE11. If you need to support them, use the long form instead (`width: width`).

You might also look in to ES2015's `class` syntax, which lets you create constructor functions and fill in the object they assign as the prototype of instances in a more concise, less error-prone way. If you need to target ES5-only browsers, there are tools like Babel to transpile for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a constructor, but just a function. `this` in the function is not an element.

Within the function you are not creating the actual box. Some properties (e.g. `this.color`) will be assigned but will not always do what you expect. Furthermore the function `box` returns nothing, so there's nothing to append.

Here's a skeleton to create an element, but I suggest you to first try learning more [JS/Html/Dom scripting](https://javascript.info/).

```js
function box (width, height, color, backgroundColor) {
  const box = document.createElement("div");
  const toPx = n => `${n}px`;
  box.style.width = toPx(width);
  box.style.height = toPx(height);
  box.style.color = color;
  box.style.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
  // return this, otherwise there's nothing to append
  return box;
}

var box1 = box(100, 100, 'white', 'red');
box1.textContent = "Hello world";
document.body.appendChild(box1);
```